# Mysql result to set session variable

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I want to use the result of a mysql query to set a session variable however at present I am struggling to make it set.

My code I have is:

```
<?php

ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

?>
<?php 
// Include required MySQL configuration file and functions 
require_once('config.inc.php'); 
require_once('functions.inc.php'); 

// Start session 
session_start(); 

// Check if user is already logged in 
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) { 
          // If user is already logged in, redirect to main page 
          redirect('../index.php'); 
} else { 
          // Make sure that user submitted a username/password and username only consists of alphanumeric chars 
          if ( (!isset($_POST['username'])) || (!isset($_POST['password'])) OR 
               (!ctype_alnum($_POST['username'])) ) { 
                        redirect('../login.php'); 
          } 

          // Connect to database 
          $mysqli = @new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
// Check connection 
          if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
                        printf("Unable to connect to database: %s", mysqli_connect_error()); 
                        exit(); 
          } 

          // Escape any unsafe characters before querying database 
          $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
          $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 

          // Construct SQL statement for query & execute 
          $sql              = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . md5($password) . "'"; 
          $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 

// If one row is returned, username and password are valid 
          if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) { 
                        // Set session variable for login status to true 

                        $_SESSION['auth_lvl'] = $Auth_lvl;
                        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;


                        redirect('../index.php'); 
          } else { 
                        // If number of rows returned is not one, redirect back to login screen 
                        redirect('../login.php'); 
          } 
} 
?>
```

I am then testing the session variables with:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
echo "Login Status is:".$_SESSION['logged_in'];
echo "<br/>";
echo "Auth status is level:".$_SESSION['auth_lvl'];
?>
```

On my testing page the session logged in works fine displaying the correct information however the auth lvl variable displays nothing.

I can only assume that I am not calling the information correctly that I am setting the variable with in the first place.

Any help would be appreciated.

Alan.

Something I have notice and I have been trying the suggestions is that if I set a definative rather than trying to retreive a value from the database that value will return on my test page. i.e.

```
$_SESSION['auth_lvl'] = 'test';
```

This tells me it is the way in which I am pulling the data from the database and trying to set it as $_SESSION['auth_lvl'] that is causing the problem.

Comment: Please provide the columns of the users table. $Auth_lvl does not have a value and this results in null being set to $_SESSION['auth_lvl']. You most likely need to assign a value to $Auth_lvl: $row = $result->fetch_row(); $Auth_lvl = $row['auth_lvl'];

Comment: @Kenny The columns are:
id(Auto inc)
username
password
Auth_lvl

I tried your suggested piece of code but no joy.

Comment: Above `$_SESSION['auth_lvl'] = $Auth_lvl;` add the following: `$row = $result->fetch_row(); var_dump($row);` and see what $row contains.

Comment: @Kenny I put the code suggested however I am not sure what or where is is supposed to display something?? The page that sets the session forwards the user onto the index page once they are logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

the code read:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql); 

// If one row is returned, username and password are valid 
if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) { 

// ADD THIS SET OF LINES
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );

// Replace auth_lvl with the name of your database column name
$Auth_lvl = $data['Auth_lvl'];


// Set session variable for login status to true 
$_SESSION['auth_lvl'] = $Auth_lvl;
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

Because I had used mysqli on this code I had not notice that on the //ADD THIS SET OF LINES piece of code that an 'i' was missing. When I changed the code to:

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );
```

Everything fired into life.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anywhere that you have assigned $Auth_lvl with a value, so when you do:

```
$_SESSION['auth_lvl'] = $Auth_lvl;
```

It's presumably getting assigned null.

Comment: thats correct it displays nothing Auth status is level:
Im trying to set it in the area of code Dan is talking about however with little avail. I have tried the code dan suggests however it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where you are setting $Auth_lvl.  After you check for the results being there, and rows, you're going straight to setting a session variable against an empty variable.

```
      if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) { 
                    // ADD THIS SET OF LINES
                    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );

                    // Replace auth_lvl with the name of your database column name
                    $Auth_lvl = $data['auth_lvl']'

                    // Set session variable for login status to true 

                    $_SESSION['auth_lvl'] = $Auth_lvl;
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;


                    redirect('../index.php');
```

Then with your logged_in session variable, you're setting it as a boolean, true, and then trying to echo it out as normal text.

```
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] ) { echo "Login status is: True"; }
```

I hope that helps.

-Dan

Comment: Dan your right about echoing the boolean result but this is only testing to see that when I added in this new auth lvl piece of code that the original was working so it did not have to be pretty or read nicely on screen

Comment: Small typo dan, `$Auth_lvl = $data['auth_lvl']'` -> `$Auth_lvl = $data['auth_lvl'];`

Comment: It almost sounds like you're losing your session somewhere.  Are you on a single server, or using any type of different session handling other than file level?